# How to send data from kafka to spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to send my data from kafka to Spark.

I have installed spark in my system and kafka  is also working in my system in proper way.

Comment: So 4 downvoted and 1 close vote ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Kafka connector from Spark. Technically, Kafka won't send the data to Spark. In fact, Spark pull the data from Kafka.

Here the link from the documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html